# Plotly express Choropleth highlight specific states

Tags: python, plotly

I have generated a choropleth using plotly express. I am plotting the population of each state and I would like to highlight the state with the largest population and the smallest population. Is there a way to change the boarder color for a specific state?

current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("state_pop.csv")

fig = px.chorolpeth(df,
                    locations="state",
                    scope="usa",
                    color="population",
                    locationmode="USA-states",
                    color_continuous_scale="blues",
                    )
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar data in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#customize-choropleth-chart) and used it to change the color of the boundaries between the states with the largest and smallest export value. The coloring order is drawn alphabetically by state abbreviation, so please specify the index of maximum and minimum in your data

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

color_list = ['blue' if x == 2 or x == 5 else 'white' for x in range(1,len(df)+1,1)]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'],
    z=df['total exports'].astype(float),
    locationmode='USA-states',
    colorscale='Reds',
    autocolorscale=False,
    marker_line_color=color_list, 
    colorbar_title="Millions USD"
))


fig.update_layout(
    height=500,
    title_text = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State',
    geo_scope='usa', # limite map scope to USA
)

fig.show()
```

[image]